# git clone error. Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

While try to clone project from Mooveb getting below error.

---

```
$ git clone moov@git.moovweb.com:skoteeswaran/ving-test.git
```

> Cloning into 'ving-test'...
>
> Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You at least need to check that `ssh moov@git.moovweb.com` (and if not, check the output of `ssh -Tvvv moov@git.moovweb.com`)

The issue could be:

- client-side (port 22 blocked) or
- server-side

  - (name or repo name incorrectly written, or with wrong case)
  - error on the sshd (daemon) side

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes, it was blocked by office network. I tried with home network, it worked and cloned the repo. Could you let me know how to unblock this to office network.?

Comment: @user3771543 only an network admin guy at your office could answer your request and establish an exception in their firewall, if he/she thinks you need that access. But I know that where I work, this would *never* be granted: outgoing *encrypted* data is frowned upon, because there is no way to monitor *what* is going outside.